# 'confirm is not a function error' with link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I try to add a confirm dialogue box on a button but it doesn't work, and generates an error:

my code:

```
<%= link_to restaurant_survey_path(@restaurant, id: @survey.id), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete do %>
    <i class="fas fa-times" style="color: gray; margin-top: 1%; font-size: 20px;"></i>
<% end %>
```

the error:

[image: error]

also my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

my `application.html.erb`:

```
...
</head>
  <body>
    <%= render "/shared/flashes" %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <script>AOS.init();</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in `application.js` file?

Comment: Nope I have just that

Comment: Do you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: I have it in my `Gemfile.lock` but not in my `Gemfile`

Comment: Can you add it to the `Gemfile`, call `bundle install`, restart the app and check if it works?

Comment: Doesn't work, same error

Comment: Can you open browser console, reload the page (without clicking the button) and check if you have any errors there?

Comment: Yes, I don't have any other errors..

Comment: One last idea - can you remove `//= require rails-ujs`, refresh the page and try clicking on the link?

Comment: still the same.. Thanks a lot anyways

Comment: Another question - can you please add `application.html.erb` to your question? To show how you include JS in your view.

Comment: Try changing the link_to to button_to. Could be the way it’s combing for the delete method (not normally done via links).

Answer (score 0):

Your application.js file is not correct, you were supposed to use an underscore not a hyphen:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-the-jquery-rails-gem